# Erro in unlink (PHP)

Tags: php, unlink

i dont no why, but i have this in error_log..

```
> [Sun Sep 08 07:31:50 2013] [warn] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_fcgid:
> stderr: PHP Warning: 
> unlink(./sys/687474703a2f2f75706c6f616465642e6e65742f667171327a377a6f):
> No such file or directory in
> /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxx/httpdocs/lib/xxx.php on line 356
```

Here the line...

```
if (file_exists('./cache/'.$FileMd5))
 if(filesize('./cache/'.$FileMd5) < "3000000")
  if(unlink('./cache/'.$FileMd5))
   $Delete=true;
  else
   $Delete=false;
```

The line is if(unlink('./cache/'.$FileMd5))

=/

Comment: `No such file or directory`, do you understand the error message?

Comment: @ComFreek Read the code. He's doing a file_exists() before, so it should not reach the unlink().

Comment: Yes, but i put the unlink after the file_exists function.. So, this file exist!

Comment: The file should not exist ... where are your brackets? `{}` ?

Comment: How could this happend? oO I already try unlink('./cache/'.$FileMd5) without the "if" .. Same error ..

Comment: i think in this case, there's no diference with or without the brackets ... But anyway, in my code i have them, i just remove to put here..

Comment: There is no need for brackets here. The else always corresponds to the direct previous if.

Comment: @user758499 Make sure the unlink that fails is this one.

Comment: Line 356, i'm sure that this is the right line ...

Comment: unlink error shows folder "sys", and your unlink line "cache", so not the same!?

Comment: hnnnnn, maybe if another process is putting the file "LOCKED"... Like flock, is that eny way that this is the problem?

Comment: @user758499: Can you try [this](http://hastebin.com/loqawugope.php)?

Comment: i change to sys here, but is the /cache/ folder... The problem isn`t the directory because i check if the directory is valid before the unlink ..

Comment: @AmalMurali, my code is already like this! But anyway, there's no diference beetween put the brackets or not in this case...

Comment: Is there any chance that the file in question is really a directory, if I'm write the previous ifs would still pass but the unlink would fail -- although you should get a different error message. Are there any symlinks in the parent directory structure?

Comment: @SpaceDog, There's no directorys inside /cache ...

Comment: @user758499, yeah it was a bit of a long shot -- in that case I can't see anything obviously wrong with that code. I'd guess it's permissions or file locking, but again that should give a different error message. I assume there's no chance that any other process changes the value of `$FileMd5` between the different checks?